# Open accordion if clicked OR search query > 0 (not sure how to do the OR part)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get the accordion to open if the user has typed something into the search bar or if someone clicks to open the accordion, I got them to work separately but I can't get both to work at the same time.

If i do this

```
<accordion-group is-open="status.open" ng-repeat="cat in cats | filter: query">
```

The accordion only opens when the user clicks, and if i do this

```
<accordion-group is-open="query.length > 0" ng-repeat="cat in cats | filter: query">
```

The accordion only open after the user has searched something

Is there any way to put those two together? I've tried this but it didn't work

```
<accordion-group is-open="query.length > 0 || status.open" ng-repeat="cat in cats | filter: query">
```

Here's my code in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/goL848jn/3/

Comment: have you tried, in your controller, to check when query.length > 0 and if so, set status.open to true? so that way you only have to use status.open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need this inside the controller

```
$scope.$watch("query",function(newv){
    if(newv != undefined){
        if(newv.length > 0){
               $scope.open = true;
               $scope.$apply;
        }else{
               $scope.open = false;
               $scope.$apply;
        }
     }   

});
```

and the accordion

```
<accordion-group is-open="open" ng-repeat="cat in cats | filter: query">
            <accordion-heading style="padding:0px;"> <i class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-minus': open, 'glyphicon-plus': !open}"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{cat.title}}</accordion-heading>
```

working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0ynqomrt/

Comment: This code may be improved... but its a good starting point :)

Answer (score 1):

Your jsfiddle accordions don't seem to be working for me...

I think your key is to have the is-open tied to a variable in your controller scope.  The accordion-group creates it's own scope.  So try something like this first:

```
<accordion-group heading="CATS" is-open="$parent.openMe">
```

Check out more what I mean in this plunker.  I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but hopefully it gets you on the right path?

http://plnkr.co/edit/uwxza87gEsCxopecAlCd?p=preview